# WebPack: problem when compiling JS files in html

Tags: javascript, webpack

I am having a problem while working with Webpack. I'm using a JS file to call an API, but this API should be called only in escudos.html, but when I do the Webpack build, the JS file calls the API int both (index.html, escudos.html). I only want that the ./src/js/teams.js call API when I am in the escudos.html, not in in both (index.html, escudos.html) HTML.

```js
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    index: './src/js/index.js',
    teams: './src/js/teams.js',
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'js/[name].bundle.js',
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: 'index.html',
      template: './src/index.html',
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: 'escudos.html',
      template: './src/escudos.html',
    }),
  ],
  devServer: {
    static: './dist',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: { loader: 'babel-loader' },
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

for some reason my webpacked file index.html has the **teams.js** too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem (and the solution) is in HtmlWebpackPlugin. HtmlWebpackPlugin injects all entries in every page by default.
There exists three solutions I can think of:

1. `inject: false`: This disables auto injection of `<script>` tags into the templete. You have to manually write `<script>`tag(s) with the proper src. (Psss: don't)
2. `chunks`: specifiy which entries you want to be included for this template. E.G: (Solves the OP problem, what you will need/use in most cases)

   ```js
   new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
       template: "./src/index.html",
       chunks: ["index"]
   }),
   new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
       template: "./src/escudos.html",
       chunks: ["teams"]
   })
   ```
3. `exclude`: inject all entries except the ones specified in this array. E.G

   ```
   new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
       template: "./src/test.html",
       exclude: ["index"]
   })
   ```